# Entity Framework 6 Code First Fail

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm new in Entity Framework and I'm testing a simple application but it doesn't work.
   Let me explain step by setp what I'm doing:

1- Create a Console App using VS 2013 Express

2- Include a reference to EF6 by Nuget

3- Create the Student Class:

namespace CSharp_CodeFirst

{

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

}

4- Create the context class

using System.Data.Entity;

namespace CSharp_CodeFirst

{

```
public class StudentDataContext : DbContext
{
    public StudentDataContext() : base()
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Student> Students;
}
```

}

5- Create the code in Program.cs

namespace CSharp_CodeFirst

{

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (var ctx = new StudentDataContext())
        {
            Student stud = new Student() { name = "New Student", email="test@test.com" , Id=1 };

            ctx.Students.Add(stud);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

}

6- Build without errors

7- When I execute the project I get the error :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in CSharp_CodeFirst.exe
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The error occur in this line of code : ctx.Students.Add(stud);

I'm using the sample in this site : http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx

I Feel Like I'm Forgetting Something, but What ???

Thanks

Comment: Use debugger and see in which line you get an error. Regarding the error msg: it's a pretty common error, you forget to properly create an instance of some object.

Comment: Make sure that you have a correct connection string in your cofig file, and also you may need to set the initialiser of your dataconext.

Comment: Hi, but in Code First, EF will not create the database and tables using the standard conventions ?

Comment: The error occur in line : ctx.Students.Add(stud);  the inner exception is Null.  It seems that Students is null, but Code-First should not create this object ?

Comment: Try initialize data by using constructor and adding data to property by using anonymous object.